# SQLPackage Deployment Failure

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac, sqlpackage

I'm using an Azure DevsOps Release Pipeline, which has the Deploy DacPac step. It's failing with no useful error. Where do I even start trying to debug something like this?

```
2023-10-31T11:52:53.2467107Z ##[debug]Initializing deployment (Start) 
2023-10-31T11:52:53.2478476Z ##[debug]Initializing deployment (Complete) 
2023-10-31T11:52:53.2491000Z ##[debug]Analyzing deployment plan (Start) 
2023-10-31T11:52:53.2503313Z ##[debug]Analyzing deployment plan (Complete) 
2023-10-31T11:52:53.2515949Z ##[debug]Updating database (Start) 
2023-10-31T11:52:53.2527690Z ##[debug]An error occurred while the batch was being executed. 
2023-10-31T11:52:53.2540412Z ##[debug]Updating database (Failed) 
2023-10-31T11:52:53.2707612Z ##[debug]Time elapsed 0:00:28.40
```

Comment: It will be difficult to guess the exact issue causing this generic error? please add some more information

Comment: Everything finished within one second, I guess there was no real attempt to deploy anything. Maybe some paths are wrong. I don't work with Azure but others do, show your pipeline config this will give us at least some details.

Answer (score 0):

As a way to troubleshoot this issue, please try the following steps:

1. Check [the logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops) of the deployment task for more information about the error. You can do this by enabling the [debug mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#run-a-release-in-debug-mode) in your pipeline, setting the variable system.debug to true, and then running the pipeline again. This will show more details about the execution of the task.
2. Based on the error message, there seems to be a successful connection to the database, but make sure you test the credentials to connect to the database using SQL Server Management Studio or PowerShell. Enable "Allow access to Azure services" on the Azure SQL firewall also.
3. Try using the /p:AllowIncompatiblePlatform option in SqlPackage.exe, in case the dacpac has some incompatibilities with Azure SQL.
4. Review the deployment options, parameters and settings in the task,

Comment: 1. I'm already in debug more. 
2. Database connection is fine. 
3. Didn't work. 
4. It's DropObjectsNotInSource which is causing the error.

Comment: Maybe adding this /p:DoNotDropObjectTypes=Permissions;Users (for example) along with DropObjectsNotInSource can help